# PHP Facebook: Retaining last session

Tags: facebook, session

I have a web application where a user can connect and login via facebook. Everything is fine. But 1 issue is there that I am failed to deal with.

When I login with one account and then try to login with a different account in the same browser, I see the old account's information.

Can you please tell me what is the best way to deal with this ?

Thank you 
ZH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

facebook still maintains a session meaning facebook hasnt logged out yet, there is an answer here.

[Facebook API - Session still exists after user logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511570/facebook-api-session-still-exists-after-user-logout)

Comment: okay thanks, so do you mean that when I login from the web application it MUST logout from facebook also ?

Comment: yes it should clear session or call the facebook logout url. unless the user voluntarily logs out of facebook